# Can a Bluetooth barcode reader update a Geodatabase via ArcGIS Server on iPad?

Tags: arcgis-server, ios, hardware, ipad

I need the ability for a field operator (using an iPad) to select a feature in a geodatabase served via ArcGIS Server, and scan its barcode, which should be entered into the geodatabase as an attribute.

1) Will Esri's [ArcGIS app](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/arcgis/id379687930?mt=8) handle this capability - can it talk to an external barcode reader, and use the output of the barcode reader to edit an attribute?

2) Assuming that it can't and we need to write an our own app, are there any mechanisms within Esri's [iOS API](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/runtime-ios-sdk/) which allow talking to hardware devices?

The ideal scenario would be a wizard-based approach which prompted the user to scan the barcode when a suitable feature was clicked, then entered the resulting barcode text as an attribute. A more manual, step-by-step workaround would be acceptable if necessary.

I've assumed that an external barcode reader, connected via Bluetooth, will be necessary as it's impractical to use the iPad's own camera due to accessibility issues (eg pits).

Thanks

Comment: 'external barcode reader' correct for barcodes http://serialio.com/products/scanner/mobile/Scanfob_2002.php - Note QR codes can be read correctly from the ipad. if the id's match it can work - a custom app is likely to be required.